# Deduplication semantics with btrfs - meta-data differs, file data identical

Tags: btrfs, deduplication

So I read [this Wiki article](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Deduplication) on deduplication with btrfs. However, it doesn't describe the semantics followed by btrfs deduplication.

Assume you have a dozen files. They all contain identical data, but their user and group ownership and permissions (along with extended attributes, ACLs etc) may differ.

Will the deduplication feature of btrfs allow me to cut down the on-disk size to approximately one twelfth of the overall size before?

Hardlinks obviously won't work because their semantics imply shared meta-data (ownership, permissions).

My kernel version is 3.16.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deduplication works on a block level. If you have files with identical content but different metadata, assuming a fully deduplicated system, the whole contents will only be stored once. Even if the files are only partially identical, deduplication can save space. For example, if you had two-byte blocks and files containing

```
file1 = ABCD
file2 = AABAAB
file3 = AAB
```

then they would be stored in 5 blocks:

```
file1 = block1,block2
file2 = block3,block4,block1
file3 = block3,block5
```

If you have identical directories (i.e. directories containing files with the same names and the same inode numbers, e.g. as the result of `cp -al` or a similar file-level deduplicating incremental backup) then they too could be stored in the same blocks.

Comment: thanks. One clarification, please. Block-level in practice refers to what is often called cluster or sector ... or even below that block size?

Comment: @0xC0000022L It's the size that the filesystem considers to be the block size. That's unrelated to whatever the underlying disk might call a sector size, or to what intermediate layers (e.g. RAID) might call a block size.

Comment: fair enough, this is why I wrote *cluster* or sector. Cluster being a term used for the basic block on some file systems. Thanks again.